# How to output wp_nav_menu as <div> within a <div> container instead of an unordered list

Tags: wordpress

I want to output multiple custom menus on my custom theme. But by default all menu items will be output as an unordered list

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

But i want to have it as

```
<div class="nav-name">
    <div class="nav-menu-default-classes my-custom-class">nav item title</div>
    <div class="nav-menu-default-classes my-custom-class">nav item title</div>
    <div class="nav-menu-default-classes my-custom-class">nav item title</div>
</div>
```

How do i have to configure the wp_nav_menu parameters to get this output?

Comment: You will not be able to achieve that effect by modifying wp_nav_menu parameters.  You will need to use a filter (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140572/filter-wp-nav-menu).  BUT, you should really ask yourself why you want to replace good, semantic html (ul/li) with non-standard, non-semantic html (nested divs).

Comment: Cause it is easier to work with div elements with CSS Flexbox instead of ul li items.